# Dataflow SQL - Unsupported type Geography

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a [Dataflow SQL](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/dataflow-sql-intro) on Google Big Query and I got this error

```
Unsupported type for column centroid.centroid: GEOGRAPHY
```

I couldnt find any evidence that Dataflow SQL actually does not support Geography data and in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/sql/data-types) geography data is not mentioned at all. Is this the case, why is that and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No unfortunately Dataflow SQL does not support Geography types. It supports a subset of [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types). Only the data types listed explicitly in the page you linked are supported, it should probably be more clear about that.

Dataflow SQL relies on ZetaSQL to parse and analyze queries, and ZetaSQL does not yet support Geography (you can see the current status [here](https://github.com/google/zetasql/blob/master/docs/data-types.md)).

Unfortunately for now the only workaround is to convert any GEOGRAPHY fields to a supported type.